# Zooming into region in Pacific

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am trying to zoom into a specific region of the Marquesas Islands in French Polynesia using R and I am not sure how to find the coordinates for this region. I've only seen examples for France and Europe so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(ggplot2)
install.packages("sf")
library(sf)
install.packages("rnaturalearthdata")
library(rnaturalearthdata)

worldmap <- ne_countries(scale = 'medium', type = 'map_units',
                         returnclass = 'sf')
# have a look at these two columns only
head(worldmap[c('name', 'continent')])

ggplot() + geom_sf(data = worldmap) + theme_bw()
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = worldmap) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(?, ?), ylim = c(?, ?), expand = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in your use case you will find the [bbox finder site](http://bboxfinder.com/#-23.079732,-196.704712,-19.357794,-191.447754) helpful. It supports zooming on a world map as a leaflet, drawing a rectangle on it and copy / pasting out the extent as a set of lat long points (i.e. WGS84 / EPSG:4326 geometry).

The link above does so for the New Caledonia - which is the only part of French Polynesia that I can pull out of my head :)

[image]

You can then use the bounding box to either clip your global data at presentation level (using xlim and ylim of your `ggplot2::coord_sf()` call) or at data level (using `sf::st_intersection()` with your desired bounding box as a polygon).

Edit: to give a more specific example consider this piece of code:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# my favorite iteration of the World dataset; 
# there are others around and all work about the same...
world <- giscoR::gisco_countries

# create a polygon from the coordinates from bboxfinder.com as a base for clipping
# for more info check over here on sister site:
# https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403977/sf-create-polygon-from-minimum-x-and-y-coordinates/404001#404001

poly <- data.frame(lon = c(-196.7047, -191.4477),
                   lat = c(-23.0797, -19.3577)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), 
           crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% 
  st_as_sfc()

# a visual check of polygon
mapview::mapview(poly)
```

[image]

```
# clip world dataset to the shape of the poly polygon
clipped_world <- world %>% 
  st_intersection(poly)

# plot New Caledonia from the clipped result
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = clipped_world)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you possibly provide a code example of exactly how to do this? I am not sure exactly where to enter values from the bounding box.

Comment: This is great, but when I do this for Rapa Nui I just get a bizarre triangle, is there anyway to improve the resolution of the polygons?

Comment: The resolution will depend on level of detail of the underlying dataset - they tend to be optimized to a particular purpose; a world dataset is best suited to displaying gloabl information. Zoomed in it will get grainy. For the best result consider getting hold of Chilean shapefile. Country specific ones are usually more detailed.